# How do you close a manually created and opened ctools modal in Drupal 6?

Tags: javascript, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-ctools

Given this code that creates and opens a ctools modal in a Drupal 6 site:

```
var content = 'my content';
var title = 'my title';
Drupal.CTools.Modal.show();
$('#modal-title').html(title);
$('#modal-content').html(content);
Drupal.attachBehaviors();
```

How do I add a link in content that will close the modal?

Didn't work:

- Adding a link with class "close". This is how the right corner close link that ctools automatically adds to the modal works
- Using `onclick="Drupal.CTools.Modal.show();"`
- Using `onclick="Drupal.CTools.Modal.close();"`

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try `onclick="Drupal.CTools.Modal.dismiss()"` instead of .close().

Answer (score 0):

Based on Alexander answer, here you have another approach when you click out, the modal is dismiss.

```
$('#modalBackdrop').live("click", function(){ Drupal.CTools.Modal.dismiss(); });
```